# С помощью React Avatar Editor получить круглую картинку, отправить её на сервер и сохранить там

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, html5-canvas, react-avatar-editor

[React Avatar Editor](https://github.com/mosch/react-avatar-editor).

Делаю как в пример:

```
<Dropzone
    onDrop={this.handleDrop}
    disableClick
    style={{ width: '250px', height: '250px' }}>
    <AvatarEditor
        ref={this.refAvatar}
        image={this.state.image}
        borderRadius={125}
        width={250}
        height={250}
        border={0}
        scale={1}
    />
</Dropzone>
```

В редакторе всё выглядит правильно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обработка:

```
handleDrop = dropped => {
    this.setState({ image: dropped[0] })
};

onClickSave = () => {
    // This returns a HTMLCanvasElement, it can be made into a data URL or a blob,
    // drawn on another canvas, or added to the DOM.
    const canvas = this.refAvatar.current.getImage();

    // If you want the image resized to the canvas size (also a HTMLCanvasElement)
    const canvasScaled = this.refAvatar.current.getImageScaledToCanvas();
    const img = canvasScaled.toDataURL();
    const rect = this.refAvatar.current.getCroppingRect();
};
```

В итоге есть `canvasScaled` (тут кропнутая квадратная картинка) и `rect`.

А как дальше получить круглую картинку? В их [демке](https://react-avatar-editor.netlify.com/) в превью закруглённость получается за счёт css: `border-radius: 52.5px;`. Мне это не поможет получить круглую пикчу и отправить на сервер.

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, почему бы не закруглить на сервере? Боязнь нагрузок или ещё что-то?

Comment: @andreymal лишняя нагрузка, совсем ни к чему.

Comment: А можно ещё поинтересоваться, чем не угодил клиентский border-radius, зачем именно круглая картинка?)

Comment: @andreymal на самом деле, интересный вопрос )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Создал невидимый `canvas`.

   ```
   <canvas style={{display: "none"}}
       ref={this.refCanvas}
       width={250}
       height={250}
   />
   ```
2. В него отрисовываю кропнутую квадратную картинку.
3. Обрезаю всё, что вне круга.
4. Получаю итоговое изображение.
5. Отправляю на сервер.

Обработка теперь такая:

```
onClickSave = () => {
    const canvasScaled = this.refAvatar.current.getImageScaledToCanvas();
    const img = canvasScaled.toDataURL();
    const rect = this.refAvatar.current.getCroppingRect();

    this.drawPreview(img, rect);
};

drawPreview = (img, rect) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = img;
    image.onload = _ => {this.handleImageLoad(image)};
};


handleImageLoad = (image) => {
    const ctx = this.refCanvas.current.getContext('2d');
    const width = 250;
    const height = 250;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    ctx.arc(125,125, 125, 0, Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.clip();

    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

    axios.post('http://localhost:8081/upload', {img: this.refCanvas.current.toDataURL()}, {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};
```

На серваке обработка тривиальная, там express:

```
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body.img.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
    const buf = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
    fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/../public/image.png', buf);
});
```

Картинка получается круглая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]